# Как сделать подмену адреса файла? htaccess или php

Tags: php, .htaccess

Как сделать редирект обращения к файлу?
Например есть файл **site.ru/file.rar** 
При обращении должен загружаться из **site.ru/disk/file.rar**

Answer (score 3):

Это не на php а на стороне сервера стоит сделать если  nginx то location

```
location ^(.*).rar {
   root /your/directory/disk/;
}
```

на php только кастыли на подобие

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
// читаем файл и отправляем его пользователю
readfile($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Через .htaccess (Apache)

Регистрируете [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Настраиваете RewriteRule в .htaccess

2. Через php

Настраиваете свой сервер, чтобы в случае ошибки 404 он перебрасывал на ваш скрипт.

В скрипте анализируете url, и если нужно, отдаете нужный файл, если нет - отвечаете стандартным сообщением 404.

В обоих случаях вам нужно точно определиться в каких случаях нужно перенаправлять в disk, а в каких - нет